# Flash Compiler Errors- 1026 and 5000

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm making a space invaders type game in flash, and am going through and messing with the code because I don't necessarily know ActionScript very well, and I'm getting two errors when I'm checking to see if my enemy will come up on the screen. One error is a `1026: Constructor functions must be instance methods` and error two which is a `5000: The class SpaceVigilanteGame must subclass flash.display.MoveClip` since it is linked to a library symbol of that type. If anyone knows where I may have messed up that would be greatly appreciated.

SpaceVigilanteGame.as

```
package

{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class SpaceVigilanteGame extends MovieClip
    {
        public var enemy:Enemy;

        public function SpaceVigilanteGame()
        {
            enemy = new Enemy();
            addChild( enemy );
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy Class

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Enemy extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Enemy()
        {
            x = 10;
            y = 10; 
        }

        public function moveDownABit():void 
        {
            y = y + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks ok,  likely the problem is in how your linking to FlashPro or how/when your instantiating these classes.  When you click the edit class button in the Linkage properties for your library object (the pencil icon), do you get the right file coming up?

Comment: For which class, the Enemy Class is linked to "Enemy"

Comment: Are you doing everything inside of FlashPro? (eg code too)

Comment: I have seperate .as files that my code calls upon.

Comment: what I'm asking is where do you edit those .as files, inside of FlashPro or some other editor?

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I'm editing them inside of Flash.

Comment: Is `SpaceVigilanteGame` your documentClass?  If not, update your question to include the code where you instantiate it.

Comment: I figured out my problem, I had to go to Publish Settings, and redirect where it was calling it from. Thank you for the help sir.